# protractor error "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
describe('User report;parentCategory=Report', function() {

it('Able to open user profile by click name.;authorUID=5842;url=https://gitlab.com/savantcare/sc-wa-userreport/blob/master/tests-before-sync-to-prod/user-profile-by-click-name.js', function () {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl+'/v3/app/userreport/#/');
    afterClickURL = browser.baseUrl+'/u7/#/2_____Mark_B_Apr_01_1983';

    var forUserReportProtectorTest_1 = element(by.className('forUserReportProtectorTest_2'));
    browser.wait(forUserReportProtectorTest_1.isPresent(), 60000).then(function(){
        forUserReportProtectorTest_1.click();
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
            browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
                // fill in the form here
                browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
                expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(afterClickURL);
                browser.close().then(function () {
                    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
                        newWindowHandle = handles[0];
                        browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);


    });
});
});
```

The above code some times work and sometimes not working. Giving the error   Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details". Not only for this spaces but also where I use client side navigation. If run the test 10 times 6 times passed and 4 times failed. Please some one help.

Comment: See this answer here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/33377